# Google Play Policy of Intellectual property; why they actually accept Copyright infringement first?

Tags: google-play-services

Google said [Intellectual Property](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x_kJ8Ye107k&feature=emb_title) is very important. But for example, if I search "Among Us" there are like Among Us wallpaper, Among Us chatting (1m downloads), Among Us Tic Tac Toe and so on. I don't think none of them get the permission from Among Us company. How come Google play approved those apps?

I read many developers got experience of being closed their accounts for different reasons including against IP. So first they approved easily, and then randomly they close people's accounts that were against IP? or Google Play will stop these apps when Among Us claims?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when it comes to intellectual property google doesn't take any action regarding your apps , unless the rightful owner files a copyright claim. that's why the app gets accepted and after a while it might get suspended if the owner files a copyright claim against your app and the right resources to prove his case, you might be contacted by playstore with an email of app removal and the cause of it. so if a i create an app called "Facebook profile pictures" i can easily upload it and it stays live on the store in case Facebook didn't take actions against my app